# redirect emails from user@abc.com to user@abc.net using DNS

Tags: redirects, dns, email

Is it possible to apply the domain redirection to the email domain also?

for example:

- abc.com has a CNAME record that points to abc.net
- if I receive an email at user@abc.com is it possible to redirect it to user@abc.net?

I tried to test it out on one domain and it failed, but the domain that I tested has MX records set in it and I don't have rights update/remove them to check if it will work or not without MX records being available on the base domain name.

the whole idea is to see how can I redirect emails from users@abc.com to users@abc.net if possible.

Comment: DNS doesn't do redirects of any type either for websites or for email. I'm not sure how you have your redirect setup for your website, but it isn't through DNS.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't do this in DNS.  It has to be done on the server where the `MX Record` is pointing.

In cpanel it  would be an email forwarder.  If you don't have cpanel or a hosting panel, you will have to search for how to do it in your OS e.g. Centos, debian etc.

Comment: is it ok for two different domains to point to the same cpanel email server? or will this cause some email delivery problems?   
Also can I apply regex in the email forwarder. since I might not know the base email ?

Comment: I run a web hosting business.  There are many, many, many domains all hosted on the same cpanel server.  Assuming it is set up properly it isn't a problem.  No you can't use regex but you can do a domain forwarder i.e. all emails for example.com are forwarded to example.net